# How to show image center position inside focus view while scrolling and crop image

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I'm trying to zoom image and crop image along the focusView line.
But image's position isn't center while scrolling.
Also cropImage() doesn't crop properly.
I've already tried below code.
setup() image shows center but after scrolling, image position isn't center.
Also cropImage()

```swift
class CropImageView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var focusView: UIImage! // crop frame
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var previewImage: UIImage?
    var previewImageView: UIImageView!
    var zoomScaleView: UIView!

    func setup() {
scrollView.delegate = self
         zoomScaleView = UIView(frame: .zero)
         scrollView.addSubview(zoomScaleView) 
         previewImageView = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
         previewImageView.image = previewImage
         zoomScaleView.addSubview(previewImageView)
         scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1
         scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3
         previewImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,width: focusView.frame.width, height: focusView.frame.width)
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: focusView.frame.width, height: focusView.frame.width)
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        previewImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        previewImageView.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
         let scrollZoomScale = scrollView.zoomScale
         if scrollZoomScale == scrollView.minimumZoomScale {
            scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
            return
         }
         if previewImageView.contentClippingRect.width <= previewImageView.contentClippingRect.height {
                let difference = (previewImageView.frame.width * scrollZoomScale - previewImageView.contentClippingRect.width * scrollZoomScale)
                scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: previewImageView.frame.width * scrollZoomScale - difference,
                                                height: previewImageView.frame.height * scrollZoomScale)
                scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.init(
                    top: 0,
                    left: -difference/2,
                    bottom: (self.frame.height - focusView.frame.maxY),
                    right: difference/2)
            } else {
                let difference = (previewImageView.frame.height * scrollZoomScale - previewImageView.contentClippingRect.height * scrollZoomScale)
                scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: previewImageView.frame.width * scrollZoomScale,
                                                height: previewImageView.frame.height * scrollZoomScale - difference)
                scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.init(
                    top: -difference/2,
                    left: 0 ,
                    bottom: (self.frame.height - focusView.frame.maxY) + difference/2,
                    right: 0)
            }
    }

    func cropImage() -> UIImage {
         return previewImageView.image?.cgImage?.cropping(to: focusView.frame)
    }

}

extension UIImageView {
    var contentClippingRect: CGRect {
        guard let image = image else { return bounds }
        guard contentMode == .scaleAspectFit else { return bounds }
        guard image.size.width > 0 && image.size.height > 0 else { return bounds }

        let scale: CGFloat
        if image.size.width > image.size.height {
            scale = bounds.width / image.size.width
        } else {
            scale = bounds.height / image.size.height
        }

        let size = CGSize(width: image.size.width * scale, height: image.size.height * scale)
        let x = (bounds.width - size.width) / 2.0
        let y = (bounds.height - size.height) / 2.0

        return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    }
}
```

[Setup]
[image: Setup]

[After zooming]
[image: After zooming]

I'm struggling with this problem for long time.
Is there any solution?
Thank you.